# Import 1st package into 2nd, import 2nd package into testbench, expect to have all items visable in the testbench

Tags: simulation, system-verilog

Here I am importing a 1st package into 2nd, then importing the 2nd into a testbench.
I expect the contents of both packages to be visible in the testbench,
however the simulators on
EDA Playground are not able to find contents of the first package, and produce a corresponding error.

I am aware this can be resolved trivially by importing both into the tb.

SV Code from the left pane on EDA Playground:

```
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// 1st package
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

package my_pk_1;

  localparam TEMP1 = 1;

endpackage

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// 2nd package
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

package my_pk_2;

  import my_pk_1::*;

  localparam TEMP2 = 1;

endpackage

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// module
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

module tb () ;
  
  // import 2nd package only, because the 1st package has been imported into the 2nd
  import my_pk_2::*;

  initial 
    $display("TEMP1 = %0d",TEMP1);
  
endmodule
```

Error message:

```
xmelab: *E,CUVUNF (./testbench.sv,33|31): Hierarchical name component lookup failed for 'TEMP1' at 'tb'
```

EDA Playground Link:
[Playground](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/pxm2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In system verilog whatever you import into a package is only visible inside this package only. You need to use *export* to allow it:

> **26.6** By default, declarations imported into a package are not visible by way of subsequent imports of that package. Package export declarations allow a package to specify that imported declarations are to be made visible in subsequent imports. A package export may precede a corresponding package import

So, this should work:

```
package my_pk_1;

  localparam TEMP1 = 1;

endpackage


package my_pk_2;

  import my_pk_1::*;
  export my_plk_1::TEMP1;

  localparam TEMP2 = 1;

endpackage
```

Also there are certain rules for exporting with wildcards:

> An export of the form package_name::* exports all declarations that were actually imported from
> package_name within the context of the exporting package. All names from package_name, whether
> imported directly or through wildcard imports, are made available. Symbols that are candidates for import
> but not actually imported are not made available. The special wildcard export form, export *::*; ,
> exports all imported declarations from all packages from which imports occur.

As a result, if you want to use wildcards in export, the variable must be used in the importer package:

```
package my_pk_2;

  import my_pk_1::*;
  export my_plk_1::*;

  localparam TEMP2 = 1;
  localparam TEMP3 = TEMP1; // use of TEMP1 
endpackage
```